# How to find number of recursive call from result value?

Tags: recurrence-relations

I have following recursive equation

```
    y(0) = 0

    x(0) = 0

    y(n+1) = If((x(n)<50) then (y(n)+1) else (y(n)-1))

    x(n+1) = If((If((If((x(n)<50) then (y(n)+1) else (y(n)-1))<0) then 1 
             else 0)==0) then (x(n)+1) else x(n))
```

Where function `x(),y()` return integer and `n` natual number.

I know `x(N)==100` is true. Want to find the value of `N`. In the paper, we can try to find `x(N-1),x(N-2)...` till we are able to find `x(0)=0`. Is there any other way to do that.Please suggest

Comment: So I guess that the semantics of `If(X,Y,Z)` means "If 'X', then 'Y' else 'Z', right ?

Comment: yes I have updated in question